# bash script failing on IF statement while checking for database tables

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i have a bug with my bash script:

```
TEXISTS=$(psql -U postgres --quiet --tuples-only -d test -c "SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'test_demo');");
echo $TEXISTS
if [ "$TEXISTS" = "t" ]; then
    echo EXISTS
else
    echo CREATING       
fi
```

When I run this script, even if the test_demo table exists, it always ends up in the CREATING path...
The output from the script looks like this:

```
testbox:/tmp# sh createtabletest.sh 
t
CREATING
```

Can't seem to see my bug...

**EDIT 1**

```
testbox:/tmp# sh createtabletest.sh  
00000000  20 74 0a                                          | t.|
00000003
CREATING
```

Comment: Replace `echo $TEXISTS` by `echo "$TEXISTS" | hexdump -C` and and its output to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Please see my edit 1

Comment: `$TEXISTS` contains a leading blank. Replace `"t"` by `" t"`.

Comment: @Cyrus - cool trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$TEXISTS` contains a leading blank. Replace `"t"` by `" t"`.
                    – Cyrus